# Kotlin Flow: Why the function combine() can only take maximum 5 flows in parameters

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I notice the combine() function can only take maximum 5 flows in parameters

```
public fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R> combine(
    flow: Flow<T1>,
    flow2: Flow<T2>,
    flow3: Flow<T3>,
    flow4: Flow<T4>,
    flow5: Flow<T5>,
    transform: suspend (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) -> R
): Flow<R> = combineUnsafe(flow, flow2, flow3, flow4, flow5) { args: Array<*> ->
    transform(
        args[0] as T1,
        args[1] as T2,
        args[2] as T3,
        args[3] as T4,
        args[4] as T5
    )
}
```

Is there any particular reason behind this? (or maybe not?)

If I define a combine() taking 6 parameters in my local file, e.g.

```
private fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R> combine(
    flow: Flow<T1>,
    flow2: Flow<T2>,
    flow3: Flow<T3>,
    flow4: Flow<T4>,
    flow5: Flow<T5>,
    flow6: Flow<T6>,
    transform: suspend (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) -> R
): Flow<R> = combine(flow, flow2, flow3, flow4, flow5, flow6) { args: Array<*> ->
    transform(
        args[0] as T1,
        args[1] as T2,
        args[2] as T3,
        args[3] as T4,
        args[4] as T5,
        args[5] as T6
    )
}
```

Could this have any potential issues?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't think it should bring any issues. They probably just had to stop somewhere, and decided 5 was a reasonable number.

Comment: You could probably define it with varargs too, it would make it more convenient.

Comment: @Nicolas how you gonna resolve the type  of the combining function? For T0..TN results? Returning collection of `Any` is not applicable, `vararg` will go against the design.

Comment: there is `combine` with `vararg` in stdlib

Comment: The one with `vararg` requires the same type for parameters

Comment: most of the time, more then 5 param considered as code smell, i think that maybe one reason.  also its a design decision as well as they cant write those infinately.

Comment: To build complex lists I need sometimes more than 5 flows.

Answer (score 17):

I guess type-safe combine extensions (for 2-5 flows) is just a syntax sugar for common `combine(vararg flows)`. So there is no penalty for implementation `combine` for 6+ flows.

Implementation `combine` taking 6 flows without any cost.

```
inline fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R> combine(
    flow: Flow<T1>,
    flow2: Flow<T2>,
    flow3: Flow<T3>,
    flow4: Flow<T4>,
    flow5: Flow<T5>,
    flow6: Flow<T6>,
    crossinline transform: suspend (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) -> R
): Flow<R> {
    return kotlinx.coroutines.flow.combine(flow, flow2, flow3, flow4, flow5, flow6) { args: Array<*> ->
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        transform(
            args[0] as T1,
            args[1] as T2,
            args[2] as T3,
            args[3] as T4,
            args[4] as T5,
            args[5] as T6,
        )
    }
}
```

This is original approach in implementation combine:
[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you. Do you know how it can be extended to accept x amount of flows? Rather than defining one for 6 flows, 7 flows, etc.

Comment: @Angus Kotlin is safe-typed language, you can't just do it like in JS

Answer (score 10):

You can using the base combine function in kotlin lib:

```
   public inline fun <reified T, R> combine(
        vararg flows: Flow<T>,
        crossinline transform: suspend (Array<T>) -> R
    ): Flow<R> = flow {
        combineInternal(flows, { arrayOfNulls(flows.size) }, { emit(transform(it)) })
    }
```

Use cast if combining different types of flow, like:

```
val myDataModel= combine(
    firstParamBooleanFlow,
    secondParamBooleanFlow,
    thirdParamStringFlow,
    fourthParamStringFlow,
    fifthParamIntFlow,
    sixthParamIntFlow
){array ->
    DataModel( 
        isTrue = array[0] as Boolean && array[1] as Boolean,
        title = "${array[2]} - ${array[3]}",
        count = array[4] as Int + array[5]  as Int
        )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine them like this:

```
fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R> combine(
    flow: Flow<T1>,
    flow2: Flow<T2>,
    flow3: Flow<T3>,
    flow4: Flow<T4>,
    flow5: Flow<T5>,
    flow6: Flow<T6>,
    transform: suspend (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) -> R
): Flow<R> = combine(
    combine(flow, flow2, flow3, ::Triple),
    combine(flow4, flow5, flow6, ::Triple)
) { t1, t2 ->
    transform(
        t1.first,
        t1.second,
        t1.third,
        t2.first,
        t2.second,
        t2.third
    )
}
```